# Rails - passing object with multiple attributes to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I must pass object Product to javascript.
I've read about different methods like:

1. data-parameter, which I've already use

   ```
    <div id="chosen-product-<%=product.id %>" class="chosen-product-panel panel panel-primary"
    data-conversion="<%= product.conversion %>" data-measure="<%= product.measure %>"
   ```
2. gem gon (it looks similar)

But my problem is that Product has about 50 attributes. So I don't want to pass 50 data-parameters. How can I pass entire object (is it possible in general?) and then get his attributes in javascript? I've watched http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?autoplay=true by Ryan Bates too, but also didn't find solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your object to json:

```
<div id="chosen-product-<%=product.id %>" class="chosen-product-panel panel panel-primary"
 data-conversion="<%= product.conversion.to_json %>" data-measure="<%= product.measure.to_json %>"
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to render @product as json. Then send ajax request and get this object.**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def get_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    render json: {product: @product}
  end
end
```

---

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'products/get_product',
   success: function (product) {
     //here you get product object with all attributes
   },
   error: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
   },

});
```

Comment: Can you give me more details? I've never used json and ajax is not familiar for me. Should I specify route for this action? And how can I call this ajax function?

Comment: It is a bad idea to call the action 'get_product', when normally it should be called 'show'. Also the product Id is missing